İnfinitive and adverbial phrase as Complement to entire sentence, not one word l, such as reason or purpose or whatever
Normally grammar says that words like, because of or infinitive purpose clauses can't be used as complement  to a  sentence, unless sentence starts like this : the reason that I did something ( was because of my frustration or to get my revenge.)
However, I have come across to sentences like this a lot:

This is all because of you, Rupert.

(Clearly , "this" here refers to situation character finds himself in, but It takes because of as complement even though beacuse of is adverbial phrase.)

We did spend time together, didn't we?
That was to exchange some information.

(İf "that" here refers to purpose not entire sentence,then it is grammatical of course. But İs it really refers to purpose?)

The only time you should watch TV is to try to get relax.

(Again the whole sentence takes infinitive purpose clause(in order to) as complement.)

İn one of family guy episodes Peter was getting arrested so he asks to one of officers something like this:
İs this because I did something

(I don't remember what he asks there but again as you can see this +to be + because clause .)
P.s number 1 and 4 are from Family guy

I think #1 is mistranscribed This IS all because of you. #2 is perfectly natural; that refers to the fact that [we spent time together]. #3 is syntactically invalid / nonidiomatic (should be ...is when trying to relax or similar; what you've written is just nonsense). #4 is equally obviously just "word salad" from a non-native Anglophone. There's nothing to be learned from this.

Already vamoosed or not yet signed up here? You need to post separate questions. There are basically problems with all your sentences. Maybe you copied them incorrectly. For example: to "get relax" is not idiomatic.

I’m voting to close this question because there are too many questions in one place and some of them may be based on mishearing.

I don't see anything wrong with (4). "Is this (the arrest) happening because [I committed a crime]?

"Normally grammar says that words like, because of or infinitive purpose clauses can't be used as complement to a sentence,"  citation please!!!  Who says this?  please link to a conventional grammar site or text book that says this.

James K, any grammar site ,including Cambridge dictionary . This is wrong for example:( I studied yesterday is to improve myself, or because I wanted to improve myself)(sentence + to be + infinite or because of ) but if I add the reason In front of the sentence, grammar is correct.

My have these answers for my own questions.( If you find something incorrect, please mention it in comment.)

This is all because of you . Here this refers to reason of current event happening, not event itself. Think of it as short form of this: the reason this is happening is because of you. Unless grammar we know  changed and now we can  replace "due to" with "because of", what I wrote should be correct grammar.
In example 2, "That" refers to that purpose, not whole sentence or phrase from sentence . The purpose was to exchange some info = that was to exchange some info.
the only time we should do something is when we have to. this is correct, obviously (I feel like idiot now). What I wrote in question was nonsense.
4.again, I think Peter uses "this" to refer to the reason he is getting arrested, not the situation he finds himself in. Is this because I did something = is the reason you are arresting me because I did something.

In my experience, I have never come across to any grammar or dictionary that says we can use "this" to refer to reason of current or previous important event. That's why It had me puzzled for a while and had to ask.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
